# Keeping PowerShell window open and Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

I have a PowerShell script that I made a task for to run everyday. Is it possible to have the PowerShell window open (and not close after running) so I can make sure it runs without errors? When I schedule with the below command, no window pops up so I can't tell if it every really finished.

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File “Q:\myscript.ps1” -NoExit
```

Additionally, within the script itself, I have a line that opens a text file in Notepad (the transcript of the script from Start-Transcript). When I run the script manually, it opens up Notepad, but the scheduled task did not. Is there a setting to get that to open?

```
$validationPath = "Q:\transcript.txt"
& Notepad $validationPath
```

Comment: Is the task configured to only run when the user is logged on?

Comment: I have it set to "Run whether user is logged on or not".

Comment: Then it cannot interact with the current user's desktop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run interactively you need to select **Run only when user is logged on** under security options. From the [Task Security Context help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152(v=ws.11).aspx):

> You can specify that a task should run even if the account under which the task is scheduled to run is not logged on when the task is triggered. To do this, select the radio button labeled Run whether user is logged on or not . If this radio button is selected, tasks will not run interactively. To make a task run interactively, select the Run only when user is logged on radio button.

That said, if it is running as a scheduled task, in most cases it would be better to log the output and/or send a email on failure.

For logging you could use `Start-Transcript`, like this:

```
Start-Transcript -Path ('{0}\TaskName.{1:yyyy-MM-dd}.log' -f $env:temp, (Get-Date))
# Code here
Stop-Transcript
```

For email notifications you can use `Send-MailMessage`

```
try {
    # Code here
} catch {
    Send-MailMessage -To 'errors@domain.com' -From 'alerting@domain.com' -Subject 'Error in script TaskName' -Body "Error $($_.Message) received while running TaskName" -SmtpServer smtp.domain.com
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Unfortunately I don't think I can run when user is logged on, since our IT routinely installs updates and reboots the computers. I'll try setting it up to with email notifications!